# Using a utility method in aura controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, controller, aura

I have a common method that is to be shared between 2 aura controller methods. Is there are a way to create a single function and reuse it in both places. Example:

MyAuracontroller.js:

```
method1 :function(component, event, helper) {

  // call validate(component, event, helper);
},

method2 :function(component, event, helper) {

  // call validate(component, event, helper);
},

validate(component, event, helper){
  // common validate logic
},
```

When I tried this approach it errored out. Is there any other approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a method in the component, you have to fire an event. This will occur asynchronously, so you can't get a response back aside from firing another event, or using an asynchronous callback.

```
$A.enqueueAction(component.get('c.validate'));
```

Instead, put the method in the helper; this is the primary reason why we have helpers to begin with. They act as shared method and also shared storage between all instances of a component.

```
helper.validate(component, event);
```

Comment: much appreciated!